# Funnction to normalize input audio file of 44.1khZ sampling rate and 16 bit resolution

Tags: python, audio

I want to apply the following to an input audio file.

Input are mono audio files with 16 bit resolution at 44.1 kHz sampling rate. The audio is normalized and padded with 0.25 seconds of silence, to avoid onsets occurring immediately at the beginning of the audio file. First a logarithmic power spectrogram is calculated using a 2048 samples window size and a resulting frame rate of 100Hz. The frequency axis is then transformed to a logarithmic scale using twelve triangular filters per octave for a frequency range from 20 to 20,000 Hz. This results in a total number of 84 frequency bins.

But I was not able to implement this. I should be able to load a wav file and convert it to the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wav
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#read wav file
rate, data = wav.read('C:/...')
#convert to mono
if data.ndim > 1:
    data = data.sum(axis=1) / 2

#normalize
data = data / np.max(np.abs(data))
#pad with 0.25 seconds of silence
data = np.append(data, np.zeros(int(0.25 * rate)))
#calculate spectrogram
spec = np.abs(np.fft.rfft(data, n=2048))**2
#convert to log scale (dB)
spec = 10 * np.log10(spec)
filters = np.zeros((12, 84))
#convert to chroma
chroma = np.dot(spec, np.transpose(filters))
#convert to onset strength
onset = np.diff(chroma, axis=0)
#plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))
plt.imshow(chroma.T, aspect='auto', origin='lower', interpolation='none')
plt.show()
```

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: shapes (1025,) and (84,12) not aligned: 1025 (dim 0) != 84 (dim 0)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).